# Publishing a web application remotely

Tags: c#

i have a piece of C# code and I need to publish that so that I can get an URL which will be passed to another team for integration.

My problem is I have no access to Inetmgr due to some admin access issue.

how can I publish my web app remotely(on to my peer system )?

Answer (score 0):

Using [*WebDeploy*](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

It's an IIS add-on which opens a Web service to publish a Web site remotely.

Visual Studio and TFS Build can publish sites using WebDeploy, and you can also deploy using the command-line interface.